# Как в kotlin инициализировать двумерным ArrayList?

Tags: массивы, kotlin, arraylist

Я написал следующий код:

```
val list: ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>
```

Вроде бы я сделал правильно, но как мне его заполнить значениями, не понимаю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы его уже инициализировали пустым `ArrayList`. Если нужно сразу заполнить какими-то значениями, можно написать так:

```
val list: ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> = arrayListOf(
    arrayListOf("qwer", "aasdg", "Ssdf"),
    arrayListOf("dfgh", "dfgbnr", "gfdb")
)
```

При этом при инициализации конкретным объектом тип переменной указывать не обязательно, он будет определен по типу объекта:

```
val list = arrayListOf(
    arrayListOf("qwer", "aasdg", "Ssdf"),
    arrayListOf("dfgh", "dfgbnr", "gfdb")
)
```

Comment: При этом, тип `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` можно не указывать, он выводится автоматически.

Comment: @zed, да, дополнил ответ.